# OpenWeatherMap Starting

Tags: javascript, html, openweathermap

I have just created an account with [OpenWeatherMap](http://openweathermap.org/)

I want to get the current weather for location by City ID API Call:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=myAPIKey
```

On my html page, how do I go about using this so that I can show my users what the weather is for the specific location?

I have used Yahoo Weather API, but want to try something different.  Is the process similar?  I don't see where I would call a callbackfunction like in yahoo weather api.

Do I have to write something like this?

```
<script src="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&mode=html&appid=myapikey"></script>
```

I have tried this and it is not working.. and I couldn't find any examples on the website on how to integrate this into my html page.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

I have tried:

```
<img id="Weather-Image" src="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=myapikey" />
```

This uploads a black x.. not the picture of the current weather.

UPDATE:

I have found that I need to use ajax.. here is what I have so far:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather",
            method: "GET",
            data: { id: '2172797', appid: 'myapikey' },
            success: function (response) {
                var dataArray = JSON.parse(response);
                var weatherIcon = dataArray.weather.icon;
                var iconUrl = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + weatherIcon + ".png";
                document.getElementById('Weather-Image').src = iconUrl;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data returned from `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=myAPIKey` is described in the documentation of  [OpenWeatherMap](http://openweathermap.org/current).

You can't use it directly in a `<script>` or `<img>` tag as the response is JSON.

If you must use JavaScript to fetch the weather data, you will need AJAX (or any AJAX wrapper like `$.ajax` from jQuery) to call the API url then use `JSON.parse` to create an array with all the given data.

This is how it could look like:

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather",
  method: "GET",
  data: { id : '2172797', appid: 'myAPIKey'},
  success: function(response) {
      // response from OpenWeatherMap
      var dataArray = JSON.parse(response); // create an array from JSON element
  }
});
```

Comment: Okay, can you give me a code sample? I have found that I need to use ajax, but I am having trouble writing it

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid I added a code sample for AJAX and implemented the `JSON.parse` line.

Comment: Okay I have what you posted.  How does the `id` and `appid` get integrated into the url?

Comment: forget my question, data is appended to url for get requests

Comment: Anything else you need? I see you tried to fetch an icon already

Comment: Yes, it currently isn't working.. I am getting invalid character when i run on the line `var dataArray = JSON.parse(response);`

Comment: In that case the response you get isn't a JSON element. Use a try catch method to see the error or output the response in the JS console before parsing it to see what you get from the URL

Comment: how do I output the response?

Comment: console.log(response); before the Parse Method

Comment: it says `[object Object]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130139/discussion-between-bville-kid-and-wigi).